# Predicate in Prolog, predicate works only for numbers

Tags: prolog

I'm having trouble writing a predicate in the Prolog:

In Prolog, define a predicate `replace1(L1, L2)` that is satisfied when the list `L2` is derived from the list `L1` by replacing each element with an element of the form `element * element`.

Example: `L1 = [1, aa, 3], L2 = [1 * 1, aa * aa, 3 * 3].`

I tried this way, but this predicate only works for numbers:

```
replace1 ([], []) :- !.
replace1 ([X | Xs], [Z | Zs]) :-
  Z is X * X,
  replace1 (Xs, Zs).
```

Answer (score 4):

You are using `is/2` which is arithmetic evaluation operator. You could just use `=` and would get what you want.

```
replace([], []).
replace([X|Xs], [Y|Ys]) :-
    Y = X * X,
    replace(Xs, Ys).
```

This gives:

```
| ?- replace([1, aa, 3], X).
X = [1*1,aa*aa,3*3]
```

You can also just use pattern matching within the head itself:

```
replace([], []).
replace([X|Xs], [X*X|Ys]) :-  replace(Xs, Ys).
```